# coldfusion publish webservice using SOAP

Tags: soap, coldfusion, request, response, publishing

I am trying to create a web service that can be consumed with SOAP. I were exercising with normal webservices that returns any values, but know i want to check which elements in the SOAP:BODY are needed and return them with a response. I found the methods

> GetSoapRequest()

and

> AddSoapResponse()

in the livedoc from adobe, but don't understand how to use them. 
I saw the explenation of a request and response on [w3school.com](http://www.w3schools.com/soap/soap_example.asp)

i tried to solve the Problem with the tags "cfsavecontent"

```
<cffunction
        name="soap"
        access="remote"
        returntype="any"
        output="false">

        <cfsavecontent variable="soapMessage">
            <?xml version="1.0">
            <soap:Envelope
                xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"
                soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">

                <soap:Header>

                </soap:Header>

                <soap:Body>
                     <m:GetPriveResponse xmlns:m="namespace">
                         <m:Price>1.90</m:Price>
                    </m:GetPriceResponse>
                </soap:Body>        
             </soap:Envelope>
         </cfsavecontent>
```

but it only works, if the cffunction has returntype="any". The type "xml" occurs an error.

thx for helf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to create a web service in CF, see

Creating components for web services http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec13a13-7fe2.html

Publishing web services
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-78b7.html

Comment: I just recognized that its a web service if you add the parameter access to remote because i got the description after adding "?wsdl" but didn't think about.

Comment: But how can i set the parameters that will be called through soap. And how have the parameter be set in the soap body so, that the coldfusion web service can be received correctly.... And does the web service return automatically in the right format or what returntype do i have to set....

Comment: Read carefully, and follow the guide.  The answers are all there.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed the `soapUI` `eclipse` `addon` and called the `WSDL` that includes an argument of a complexe type. After testing the methods of my `web service` with the addon, I got the SOAP-Message I was searching all the time. Maybe it will help anybody, i just where searching long time for this solution.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"           
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:com="http://components.conner.somebody">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
          <com:echoAddress soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
          <input xsi:type="com:Address">
              <City xsi:type="xsd:string">?</City>
              <Country xsi:type="xsd:string">?</Country>
              <State xsi:type="xsd:string">?</State>
              <Street xsi:type="xsd:string">?</Street>
          </input>
          </com:echoAddress>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is the method of the coldfusion component that will be called

```
<cffunction
    name="echoAddress"
    returnType="address"
    output="false"
    access="remote">

    <cfargument
        name="input"
        type="address">

    <cfreturn #arguments.input#>
</cffunction>
```